# How to split a filename into two strings in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to split a filename into two strings, can you please tell me how to split it. For example, the following filename is given:

```
IMS_TO_GCOI_NPA_20180706
```

Is there any possibility to split the filename into two strings like following, for example by 2 words:

```
IMS_TO_GCOI_NPA_
20180706
```

Can you please give me some hints? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose i want to split by two parts by integer part and non-integer part. Python split is good choice for this. If you have more complex pattern you can use regex to do. For simple split by '_':

```
import re 

s = 'IMS_TO_GCOI_NPA_20180706'
first_part, second_part =a.rsplit('_',1)
```

or you have more comlex:

```
first_part, second_part = re.match('(.*_)(\d+)', s).groups()
```

both generates the same output.